# Find occurrence of word in a string String="My name is David.David is a student. DavidDavid lives in new york david"

Tags: string

```
String=My name is David.David is a student. DavidDavid lives in new york david"

String Match="David";
```

I need to find occurrence of `David` in this string.

Result should be = 5

What approach should I use to find that word? Earlier I was using split method and then counting but it was not giving me accurate result.

I knew it won't work as I am splitting on the basis of space. Please suggest using loops only. Not pattern and matcher.

```
String[] words= paragraph.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < paragraph.length(); i++) {
    if (words[i].equalsIgnoreCase("David")) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should specific this the language, There are thousands of languages, would be helpful to tag java and use java code formatting.

Comment: Yes , I will prefer Java. Please provide the solutio in Java language